# What is the equivalent of Firebirds "STARTING WITH" when using other databases e.g. Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, firebird

I am investigating the possibility of updating our application to work with database servers other than Firebird. We rely on "STARTING WITH" for accessing our hierarchical data. Without it, I don't see how we can migrate to another database without some serious redesign.

If you are not familiar with "STARTS WITH", it simply checks to see if a string field starts with a particular string e.g. ...

```
WHERE 'This is a test' STARTS WITH 'This is' ...
```

would return true. If a column is indexed, the index will be used for the comparison.

Do other database servers (especially Oracle/MSSQL) support "STARTING WITH" (or "STARTS WITH")?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard SQL to achieve that is something like ... WHERE 'This is a test' like 'This is%';

Comment: Will "... LIKE 'This is%' ..." use a column index if it is available? In Firebird it will, but "... LIKE '% is %' ...", wont.

Comment: That sounds very RDBMS dependent. In Oracle it would depend on the estimated cardinality of the result set, and there would still be less conventional index access methods such as a fast full index scan as options.

Comment: where name like 'norge%' will probably use an index.

Answer (score 0):

Some DB's also support WHERE LEFT('This is a test', 7) = 'This is' (although I don't remember whether this is part of the SQL standard).

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's Select has a "Start With" http://www.oracle.com/pls/db10g/db10g.show_toc?which=main&partno=b10759&maxlevel=2&section=&expand=41274">Oracle Documentation 10g for hierarchial queries. It's been part of Oracle for many years (Oracle 8 at least).

Not sure about SQL Server.

Comment: Oracles "START WITH" and Firebirds "STARTS WITH" do not have the same functionality. Oracles specifies a root row, Firebirds is a string comparator.